# Last Edit on Wiki Article by X User

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to get the text of article Y on Wikipedia. I don't necessarily want the latest version of the article, but the last version made by X user.

I do know X user made some edits to the article.

Right now I query the API by title Y the get information about recent changes to the article.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&rvprop=user|ids&rvlimit=500&titles=Y
```

I process that information to get the first revid associated with X user, and then put that into this request to get the full article text of when user X last vetted the article.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&format=json&prop=text&oldid=REVID
```

This is working now, but has a major flaw. If the user X didn't edit the page within Z edits then they're not going to appear in the revisions query. Any way I can more directly get the text for article Y last vetted by X user?

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions says  `rvuser: Only list revisions made by this user. 1.11+`

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!